# Generic class that can inherti from more than one base abstract class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, inheritance, abstract

so I am trying to build a flexible system for ScriptableVariables and ScriptableEvents (inspired by Ryan Hipple's Unite talk from 2017) in Unity and am running into some issues.

What I want to do is make class that takes in a generic which can inherit from 2 different abstract classes which both have the same base abstract class, but I am not sure if it is possible.

Example:

```
public abstract class BaseClass : ScriptableObject {}

public class ClassA : BaseClass {}
public class ClassB<T> : BaseClass {}
```

Then I want to have a separate class which takes in a Generic that can be either ClassA **OR** ClassB.

```
public class NewClass<T1> where T1 : ClassA **OR** ClassB {}
```

Is this possible? If so - what is the syntax for it? If not - what alternatives would be there to achieve something of this nature?

JetBrains Rider does not allow this stating that there's inherit conflicting constraints (which makes sense since both ClassA & ClassB would have the methods derived from BaseClass, however this suggests that T1 would inherit from both ClassA **AND** ClassB, whereas I want it to be one or the other.

It seems something of this nature is possible with interfaces, however when going about it this way - I am running into issues down the chain which seem to break my entire system, so I wanted to know if it is solvable like this before resorting to rehauling the lower systems.

Comment: `public class NewClass<T1> where T1 : BaseClass {}`?

Comment: yeah what speaks against using the common base type? Otherwise yes you could have a specific interface only `ClassA` and `ClassB` implement and use that one instead .. wouldn't see the advantage over the `BaseClass` though

Comment: Apologies! I skipped a key detail.

public class NewClass<T1, T2> where T2 : ClassA OR ClassB<T1> {}

This is what I am trying to achieve. The base class does not take in the T1 parameter that might be needed in some cases.

Comment: How would `T2` be used if that constraint were possible? Can you update your question with this information, and how `T2` needs to be used?